# ASP.Net jquery return data from web method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webmethod

I am calling a web method from jquery, It does some database stuff correctly, then it should return a string. And in Jquery, I want to get that returned string and display it in a Panel object. But I cannot get the string and cannot display it in the Panel

NOTE: The way I am accessing the Panel is correct. this works $('#<%=pnl_poll_result.ClientID %>').text("some string");

here is the code,

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ViewPost.aspx/insert_post_poll_selections",
                    data: "{'ProfessionalId':'1','choice_id':'" + $('#<%=rbl_poll.ClientID %> input:checked').val() + "','PostId':'<%=Session["SessionPostId"].ToString() %>','UserId':'<%=Session["SessionUserId"].ToString() %>'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#<%=pnl_poll_result.ClientID %>').text(data);
                    }
                });
```

here is the webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
public static String insert_post_poll_selections(String ProfessionalId, String choice_id, string PostId, string UserId)
{

 //do some database stuff

    return "return message from web method";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should debug your code in console in webbrowser to look what contains data variable. Maybe solution is simple, and you should use

```
$('#<%=pnl_poll_result.ClientID %>').text(data.responseText);
```

Comment: I checked the console and it doesnt throw any exception. weird

Comment: I changed the code to this alert(data.responseText); and it displays "undefined"

Comment: I solved the problem I had to use "alert(data.d)" to get the string